# css container not containing text

Tags: css, css-float

I'm sure this is going to be some mistake I just keep looking over but I have some divs, all floated left, I've cleared them, and they just won't contain the content.

Here it is set up http://jsbin.com/atinap/32/edit

SO this is what I have:

```
<div class="blue">
        <img id="committee_img" class="header_img"     src="http://www.brighamandwomens.org/Patients_Visitors/pcs/RehabilitationServices/icons/comitt  
ee_members_icons.png" />
  <p id="committee_txt" class="TXT_med_blue header_text">Research Committee Members</p>
  <br class="unfloat">

<div id="members_wrapper">
  <div id="members_1">

      <p class="TXT_sm_grey"> Mary O’Brien, OTR/L, CHT<br>
       Ken Shannon, PT, DPT, OCS<br>
       Rebecca G. Stephenson, PT, DPT, MS, WCS<br>
       PJ Su, MS, CCC-SLP<br>
       Reg B. Wilcox III, PT, DPT, MS, OCS
    </p>

  </div>

  <div id="members_2">

  </div>
  <div id="members_3">

  </div>
  <br style="clear:both;">
</div>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
#publications_img {
padding-top:10px;
margin-left:325px;
}  
#publications_txt {
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:302px;
}  

#committee_img {
padding-top:10px;
margin-left:318px;
}  
#committee_txt {
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:234px;
}  

#members_wrapper {
border:1px solid red;
}
#members_1 {
width:226px;
height:2px;
border:1px solid red;
float:left;
}
#members_2 {
width:226px;
height:2px;
border:1px solid blue;
float:left;
}
#members_3 {
width:226px;
height:2px;
border:1px solid yellow;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're assigning your divs a height of 2px, so of course the content will overflow.
what exactly is your goal?

Comment: hahaha, I knew it was something dumb like that, it was just so I could see them while I was setting them up, I forgot to take that out.  Thanks